# How to use jQuery .not() to select first-child only on the current level?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following list structure (which is a menu by the way):

```
<div id="mainmenu"> 
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-435">
        <li class="item-468 active deeper parent">
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="item-469 current active">
                    <a href="/index.php/news/news-topaktuell">Topaktuell</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item-480">
                    <a href="/index.php/news/events">Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-476">
        <li class="item-477">
        <li class="item-478">
        <li class="item-479">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to attach a `click()` event listener on the first `<li>`, so that it shows the header of the page. The other `<li>` tags should also have a `click()` listener, but in case of this event, the header should be hidden; the header is shown by default, so the header should only show on the home page (first-child).

What I already did:

```
$('#mainmenu .menu li:not(:first-child)').click(function() {
     //hide header
});

$('#mainmenu .menu li:first-child').click(function() {
     //show header
});
```

But this selects the first child from the sublist too, which I do not want. Is there any elegant way to select the desired tags only?

Comment: you can try `$('#mainmenu .menu').children('li:first-child')`. children only does the selection among direct descendants and does not dive any deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#mainmenu .menu > li:not(:first-child)').click(function() {
     //hide header
});

$('#mainmenu .menu > li:first-child').click(function() {
     //show header
});
```

Comment: @Andre you are right. In this case :first would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/myVs9/

Basically when you click on an LI, you want the UL contained within, to show/hide, whilst keeping the text you clicked on visible.

Hope that helps?